# How to set CI/CD with kubernetes on premise on gitlab?

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I tried to set CI/CD with Kubernetes on AWS EC2 server using GitLab as following their guideline on the GitLab page, but I faced an error message  that says the "API URL is blocked." and I saw the solution of that has to allow the options on the admin's page. But the thing is I can not find the admin area on my account. I guess I need to upgrade my account or something if I want to use its page.

BTW, I want to know both how I can find my admin's page on GitLab and guide of set CI/CD with Kubernetes on GitLab as on-premise.

Please advise to me. Thx in advance.

Comment: well, are an admin on the gitlab tool?

Comment: Does it answer your question https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/ ?